# ,VMware Fusion says that a file isn't found, but file exists

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, vmware-fusion

I recently restored all of my VMWare files from an iCloud backup. I am using VMware Fusion 11.

Whenever I start up my VM, I get an error message saying:

```
"Unable to open file /Users/username/Documents/Virtual Machines/Offsec-VMWare/OffsecVM-2018.3-20180821-cl2-000005.vmdk The system cannot find the file specified".
```

Buuuttt that file actually exists!!!!

It's not a permissions thing because the perms are set to 777.

This is driving me crazy. . .

Comment: 1. Is there possibly a permissions issue on the parent directory? 2. Does the log file report anything else?  Possibly the error message is misleading and it failed to open some other file that the reported file depends on.

Comment: That's be a no, Jim.  I changed the parent directory perm to 777 with the same result, and the log file doesn't report anything else